# Application RPM Install Error: libc.so.6 is needed by ....

Tags: glibc, rhel7

I have an application rpm which when installed is failing to get installed with error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6 is needed by testSam-4.7.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by testSam-4.7.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by testSam-4.7.x86_64
```

The system has RHEL 7.3 with glibc 2.17.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

# rpm -qf /lib64/libc.so.6
glibc-2.17-157.el7.x86_64
```

So the application built using older glibc(it needs glibc between 2.0 and 2.1) is failing to run on a system having newer glibc 2.17.

How to get rid of this issue and run the application on systems having newer glibc?
I guess there are some glibc backward compatibility packs which will help us run such applications on systems having newer glibc.
From where can I download such compatibility packs?

Comment: Thanks nos for the suggestion. But how did how concluded that it has 32 bit binaries.

Comment: I encountered this problem too. It turns out that libc.so.6 is the 32-bit library and the 64-bit library is libc.so.6(64-bit). Yes, even though we've moved onto 64-bit libraries as the default, the filenames reflect a 32-bit standard where 64-bit software was the exception that had to be annotated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the package name of testSam-4.7.x86_64 , there are probably some binaries in that rpm that are NOT 64 bit, but built as 32 bit. You might need to install the glibc.i686 package first

If there is a 32 bit executable or library in the package it will add a dependency on `libc.so.6` , while 64 bit executables adds a dependency on `libc.so.6(64bit)`

Comment: There was a 32 bit binary in the rpm but was used no more and so on removing it the issue is resolved.

Comment: How did you find that binary?